# Passing back a Promise and resolving it elsewhere

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to replace some callbacks in my code with Promises.

I have a model that runs in a loop, using setAnimationFrame. I would like kick off something in my model and notify me when it is complete. Currently I do it like this.

```
doSomething(callback) {
   this._doSomething = true
   this._doneCallback = callback
}   

step() {
  ...
  if (this._doSomething) {
    doItEveryStep();
    if (success) {
      this._doneCallback()
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
```

I'd like to use promises instead, so instead of using a callback I can use `model.doSomething().then( () => ... )`

Here's how I think it would be nice to do this:

```
doSomething() {
   this._doSomething = true
   this._successPromise = new Promise()
   return this._successPromise
}   

step() {
  ...
  if (this._doSomething) {
    doItEveryStep();
    if (success) {
      this._successPromise.resolve()
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
```

However, clearly I can't just create a `new Promise()` because I need to pass in the function that calls `resolve` to the Promise. But I'm confused, because I don't want to trigger some asynchronous code -- the asynchronous code *is already happening*. I just want to be able to have the option to trigger something to start happening in that existing asynchronous loop, and tell me when it is done.

Clearly I'm thinking of this all wrong. Should I even try to treat `doSomething` as a promise?

Comment: it sounds like what you need is an event, not a promise. though i guess in your case one wouldn't be much different from the other.

Comment: @KevinB I edited my question to use `doSomething` which is closer to my actual code, and makes it clearer why I want it to be a promise. I want to do something, then, when it's done, do something else. So `doSomething` feels like it's "thenable". But the problem is that `doSomething` itself doesn't trigger the async code, it just sets a flag in an existing loop.

Comment: If you were to use a promise, you'd want to wrap the entire thing in a promise to begin with rather than only create a promise later when you decide you need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a promise here, there are two options that I can see. First, keep the callback and use it to resolve the promise:

```
doSomething() {
   this._doSomething = true

   // The || is to prevent the promise from being recreated if this
   // method is called twice.
   this._successPromise = this._successPromise || new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this._doneCallback = resolve
   })
   return this._successPromise
}   

step() {
  ...
  if (this._doSomething) {
    doItEveryStep();
    if (success) {
      this._doneCallback() // Resolves the original promise...
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can create a helper class that wraps a promise and publicly exposes its resolve and reject functions:

```
class Deferred {
    promise;
    resolve;
    reject;

    constructor() {
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolve = resolve;
            this.reject = reject;
        })
    } 
}

doSomething() {
   this._doSomething = true
   this._successPromise = this._successPromise || new Deferred()
   return this._successPromise.promise
}   

step() {
  ...
  if (this._doSomething) {
    doItEveryStep();
    if (success) {
      this._successPromise.resolve()
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would normally have all the asynchronous code that leads to the fulfilment of the promise coded within the promise constructor callback.

It *really* you need it differently, then you *can* do it, but I my opinion is not an ideal pattern: save a reference to the `resolve` function you get from the promise constructor:

```
doSomething() {
    this._doSomething = true
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        this.resolve = resolve; // Save the reference
    })
    // We don't need a reference to this._successPromise 
}   

step() {
  ...
  if (this._doSomething) {
    doItEveryStep();
    if (success) {
      this.resolve() // We have the reference
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
```

Comment: You say we don't really need `return this._successPromise`. But doesn't `doSomething()` need to return *something*, so that we can then attach `.then` to it? Or do you just mean we don't need a named promise, and we can just `return new Promise....`?